# Synchronize byte[2400000] between threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

I want to create a big byte array in an background worker. After finished the work, the backgroundworker should give the data to the main thread.

How can I do that?

Comment: you can simple provide a reference to the main thread

Comment: use `lock`. (read the docs)

Comment: @DrKoch Why locking when the background thread is done?

Comment: With multiple threads it is **important** to lock common memory before accessing it. This will avoid that the main thread does something with the memory **while** backgroundworker modifies it.

Comment: @DrKoch The memory is accessed _after_ the background thread is done with it, so there is no concurrent handling and no need for locking.

Answer (score 6):

In your background worker [`DoWork` event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork), use the `Result` member of the `DoWorkEventArgs` parameter to return the byte array.

Then, in your background worker [`RunWorkerCompleted` event handler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted), read the `Result` member of the `RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs` parameter.

**DoWork** example from the linked MSDN documentation:

```
// This event handler is where the actual, 
// potentially time-consuming work is done. 
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, 
    DoWorkEventArgs e)
{   
    // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

    // Assign the result of the computation 
    // to the Result property of the DoWorkEventArgs 
    // object. This is will be available to the  
    // RunWorkerCompleted eventhandler.
    e.Result = ComputeFibonacci((int)e.Argument, worker, e);
}
```

**RunWorkerCompleted** example from the linked MSDN documentation:

```
// This event handler deals with the results of the 
// background operation. 
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown. 
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {
        // Next, handle the case where the user canceled  
        // the operation. 
        // Note that due to a race condition in  
        // the DoWork event handler, the Cancelled 
        // flag may not have been set, even though 
        // CancelAsync was called.
        resultLabel.Text = "Canceled";
    }
    else
    {
        // Finally, handle the case where the operation  
        // succeeded.
        resultLabel.Text = e.Result.ToString();
    }

    // Enable the UpDown control. 
    this.numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;

    // Enable the Start button.
    startAsyncButton.Enabled = true;

    // Disable the Cancel button.
    cancelAsyncButton.Enabled = false;
}
```